# How to capture all but last token in regex when last token can be optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the following format:
`aaa!bbb.200`
where

- `aaa` can be anything (any length)
- `bbb` can be anything (any length) except `!`
- `!` & `.200` are optional (can be any 3 digit number)

i want to capture `bbb` and `200`

for example:

1. `aaaaa!bbbb.200` i want to capture `bbbb` & `200`
2. `aaa.400` i want to capture `400`
3. `aaa!bb` i want to capture `bb`

i have been able to do this with the following regex `(?:.*!(.*)\.(\d{3}$)|.*!(.*)|.*\.(\d{3}$))`
but it uses `|` which complicates the capturing groups, and also seems too long for what i need

trying to capture all but optional last, ends out consuming all string before checking optional.

Comment: Try `^.*?(?:!([^!\n]*?))?(?:\.(\d{3}))?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/CMjRKa/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works , thanks !
i see the way to look at it was 
take all (non greedy) then take optional  `!`  that has no `!` after it. nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?(?:!([^!]*?))?(?:\.(\d{3}))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CMjRKa/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:!([^!]*?))?` - an optional sequence matching one or zero occurrences of a `!` char and then any zero or more chars other than `!` char as few as possible, captured into Group 1
- `(?:\.(\d{3}))?` - an optional sequence matching one or zero occurrences of a `.` char and then any thre digits, captured into Group 2
- `$` - end of string.